# SceneKit SCNNode SNCAction.fadeIn not behaving as expected, it simply pops in

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

Im playing with SceneKit to get familiarised with it. Im trying to do fade in some nodes and move them down. Now all seems to work, except the fadein animation.
Here is the code

```
let arrowShape = SCNPlane(width: 1, height: 0.3)
let arrowMaterial = SCNMaterial()
arrowMaterial.lightingModel = .constant
arrowMaterial.isDoubleSided = false
arrowMaterial.transparencyMode = .singleLayer
arrowMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named:"unnamed.png")
arrowMaterial.blendMode = .add                    
arrowShape.materials = [arrowMaterial]
let arrowNode = SCNNode(geometry: arrowShape)
arrowNode.opacity = 0.0
arrowNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, 0.2, 0)
arrowNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 1, 0.1)
planeNode.addChildNode(arrowNode)
            
let apearAction  = SCNAction.fadeIn(duration: 0.1)
let action = SCNAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: -1, z: 0, duration: 1)
let group = SCNAction.group([apearAction,action])
let removeAction  = SCNAction.removeFromParentNode()
let sequence = SCNAction.sequence([group, removeAction])
arrowNode.runAction(sequence)
```

But for some reason the arrow simply appears and moves down. I have tried just adding the fadein without movement and same results. I believe it has to do with the materials but Im not sure.
I though this would be as easy as UIView.animate...  methods.. :)

[image]

Thanks in advance, and forgive me if I asked some dummy question.

Comment: Try to make your fadeIn Action a tick longer, like 0.5 or 0.3 seconds.

Comment: @zay Did so even 5 secs didn't work. The arrow just pops. :(